# удалить атрибут сессии после рендеринга на странице xhtml

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Я на xhtml странице вывожу атрибут сессии. После этого надо его удалить. Как это сделать правильно?

```
<h:outputLabel class="logoutTime" value="#{loginMsg.u}"
                       rendered="#{request.session.getAttribute('login') != null}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, что вы изобретаете ̶в̶е̶л̶о̶с̶и̶п̶е̶д̶ Flash Scope. Если стоит задача вывести что-то ровно один раз, то лучше сделать это так:

**SomeBean.java**

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {
    public String someRedirect() {
        Flash flash = FacesContext
                        .getCurrentInstance()
                        .getExternalContext()
                        .getFlash();
        flash.put("someAttr", true);
        return "some-page?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

**some-page.xhtml**

```
<h:outputLabel class="logoutTime" value="#{loginMsg.u}" rendered="#{flash.someAttr}"/>
```

Comment: ManagedBean
RequestScoped
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("sessionTimeOut", request.getParameter("sessionTimeOut"));

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(request.getContextPath());

Comment: выдает ошибку nullpointerexception